# import fortran object into Python

Tags: python, fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to compile some project I've found on the web.
the project is wrapping some Fortran code into python object.

The author of that project wrote I need to run the setup.py file.

I've done that. It contains the following piece of code:

```
  ext = Extension(name = "GaussianFitter._Fitter",
                sources = ["GaussianFitter/src/lmdif.f",
                           "GaussianFitter/src/splev.f",
                           "GaussianFitter/src/gaussian.f90"],
```

and obviously all these "f" files are existing.
When I install that setup.py file it seams to do some job succesfully but the first line in the script which uses that _Fitter:

```
import _Fitter
```

doesn't work.

I'm newby with python, and have no experiment with Fortran at all, so please forgive my ignorance.

Edit: project available here:

https://github.com/ardiloot/GaussianFitter

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by “it doesn’t work”? Does it throw an error? Which?

Comment: Hi - I'm working with pyCharm and getting a red line under the import. If trying to run- I get a cannot import error. Thanks

Comment: Is there some error message? Please find some drtails.

Comment: Thanks - yes, finally got something. I probably failed to install mingw, I ran now the install file using parameter "install" on self.ld_version which is "none_type" which I guess means it couldn't find the compiler...

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues - I'm using following line: from numpy.distutils.core import setup, and then calling the setup function. Do you know how to specify which compiler to use? where it is etc? some link? Thanks!

Comment: How to compile a project without **LSB** ? `Core` required compile module form source code, actually , if success to make, maybe never work on other machines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally made it, so here's my for-begginers tutorial:

note - since it's for beginners - it sets all in the global scope.

1. install mingw32 from:
   http://www.mingw.org/
   Add it's bin path to system PATH.
2. add a setup.cfg file containing the following text:

   [build]

   compiler=mingw32

locate it in %pythondir%\Lib\distutils

3. since setup.py file contains links to .c or .f files (c++/fortran/c) in order to make command (python setup.py install) be able to locate these files - run the command when working directory (i.e. cd c:....\) is set.
4. Ignore red error line in code when you import that module. It is in the LIB directory, just try to run...

EDIT:

If still not managing to import the already built f files - building it in the following way might help:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

which generates an object (*.pyd), this helped me after it, for any reason, stopped working.